# Cursor in a Oracle pipe row function

Tags: oracle

I have a pipelined function like this one:

```
pipe row(mytype('1','1','1'));
pipe row(mytype('2','2','2'));
pipe row(mytype('3','3','3'));
pipe row(mytype('4','4','4'));
return;
```

and I have another procedure that read this, using a cursor:

```
for c_cursor in(
  SELECT field1 FROM table(mytable)) 
loop
  v_Var1:=c_cursor.field1;
  if((v_Var1 = '1')) then
    return;
  end if;
end loop;
```

I need to know if Oracle will process the other rows (2,3 and 4) after the `return`, or it will stop the pipeline.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *process* the rows?

Comment: Put a `DBMS_OUTPUT` after RETURN and see yourself.

Comment: The problem was the "For" cursor. I did a test with "Open" cursor and works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy to test:

```
create function pipetest return sys.odcinumberlist pipelined as
begin
  for i in 1..5 loop
    pipe row(i);
    dbms_output.put_line('Piped ' || i);
  end loop;
  return;
end;
/

set serveroutput on size unlimited
begin
  for r in (select * from table(pipetest)) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Got ' || r.column_value);
    return;
  end loop;
end loop;
/

anonymous block completed
Piped 1
Piped 2
Piped 3
Piped 4
Piped 5
Got 1
```

But how many rows depends on the fetch size; if you pipe 1000 rows instead:

```
create function pipetest return sys.odcinumberlist pipelined as
begin
  for i in 1..1000 loop
...
```

Then (for me anyway) it stops after the first batch fetch:

```
anonymous block completed
Piped 1
Piped 2
Piped 3
... <snipped for brevity> ...
Piped 97
Piped 98
Piped 99
Got 1
```

So the first fetch got 100 rows before the calling block started to loop over them. If I change the return to happen later:

```
if r.column_value = 101 then
  return;
end if;
```

Then I see:

```
anonymous block completed
Piped 1
Piped 2
Piped 3
...
Piped 97
Piped 98
Piped 99
Got 1
Got 2
Got 3
...
Got 96
Got 97
Got 98
Got 99
Got 100
Piped 100
Piped 101
Piped 102
Piped 103
...
Piped 197
Piped 198
Piped 199
Got 101
```

So the function may process more rows after the caller returns, but it won't necessarily process all of them.

As you mentioned in a comment, if you open the cursor and fetch a single row at a time, it behaves differently:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare
  cursor c is select * from table(pipetest);
  n number;
begin
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c into n;
    exit when c%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('Got ' || n);
    if n = 3 then
      return;
    end if;
  end loop;
  close c;
end loop;
/

anonymous block completed
Got 1
Piped 1
Got 2
Piped 2
Got 3
```

The function still stops processing when you stop fetching. The only difference here is that the fetch size is 1. With bulk collect it behaves like the original 'for' loop, but you can play with the limit clause to see the effect that has;

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare
  cursor c is select * from table(pipetest);
  t sys.odcinumberlist;
begin
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c bulk collect into t limit 10;
    for i in 1..t.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Got ' || t(i));
      if t(i) = 3 then
        return;
      end if;
    end loop;
    exit when t.count < 10;
  end loop;
  close c;
end loop;
/

anonymous block completed
Piped 1
Piped 2
Piped 3
Piped 4
Piped 5
Piped 6
Piped 7
Piped 8
Piped 9
Got 1
Got 2
Got 3
```

If you're worried about side effects from the function, the only way to stop it doing processing beyond your caller's stop condition is to do single-row fetches.

Comment: Instead of "for loop" cursor, if we use "open.. fetch", looks like it process which row, one by one.

Comment: @paulo - yes, I've shown that; but bulk collect still does batches.